# Error while importing shapefile data using LayerMapping in GeoDjango

Tags: shapefile, geojson, geodjango, django

I am facing an issue while importing shapefile data using LayerMapping in GeoDjango. I have defined a model `Province` with two fields - `province_name` and `province_shapefile`. The `province_shapefile` field is of type `PolygonField` from `gismode`' in GeoDjango. I am trying to import data using a script `load_data.py` which uses LayerMapping to map the fields in the shapefile to the model fields. However, I am getting an error

> An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the `atomic block`.

I have tried wrapping the code inside `transaction.atomic`, but it does not seem to work. How can I address this issue?